# How to normalizing data in pythons pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database-normalization

I have a problem normalizing data in pandas.

```
In [37]:
import pandas as pd # data processing
from IPython.display import display
```

This is my dataset I have ...

```
In [37]:
d = {'FTR': ['W', 'D', 'L', 'W'], 'HTG': [3, 0, 1, 2], 'ATG': [0, 0, 2, 0], 'HTN': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta'], 'ATN': ['Beta', 'Chi', 'Epsilon', 'Alpha']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)

    FTR HTG ATG HTN     ATN
0   W   3   0   Alpha   Beta
1   D   0   0   Alpha   Chi
2   L   1   2   Alpha   Epsilon
3   W   2   0   Beta    Alpha
```

... and so I would like the data to have

```
d = {'FTR': ['W', 'D', 'L', 'W'], 'HTG': [3, 0, 1, 2], 'ATG': [0, 0, 2, 0], 'HTN': [1, 1, 1, 2], 'ATN': [2, 22, 5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)

    FTR  HTG  ATG  HTN  ATN
0   W    3    0    1    2
1   D    0    0    1   22
2   L    1    2    1    5
3   W    2    0    2    1
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a preset map of names to numbers? i.e. `{'alpha':1, 'beta':2, ...}`

Comment: That isn't normalizing, thats encoding. You can use `map` or `replace`  functions if you have a dictionary with matching values . Or you can use `pd.factorize()`

Comment: @Dark, The dup doesn't answer how to ensure consistent factorization *across series*. Can you find a more suitable dup? If not, I think it's worth a demonstration.

Comment: @jpp I added that too to the duplicates. Yeap ensuring encoding across multiple columns is necessary for the OP I guess.

Comment: @creep3007, Not all the dup solutions preserve ordering (first value met has code 0). I've added a solution to the second duplicate which accounts for this.